# How can I insert conditional statement inside the list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list lst and I want to split its elements if they are numbers. So the  format of my lst is like:

```
lst=["1,2,3"," , , ","4,5,6"]
```

And I have an expression like below but I want to do `int(i)` if there is a number not a blank. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
[[int(i) for i in c.split(',')] for c in lst]
```

What I need is:

```
[1, 2, 3, " ", " ", " ", 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: so the final result should be `[1, 2, 3, " , , ", 4, 5, 6]`? That does not look good; are you sure?

Comment: @Kounis Oops,sorry. What I need is `[1, 2, 3, "  ", " ", " ", 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Edit the question to include this info please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *got-to-do-everything-with-list-comprehensions* way:

```
lst=["1,2,3", " , , ", "4,5,6"]

res = [int(x) if x!=' ' else x for y in lst for x in y.split(',')]
print(res)  # [1, 2, 3, ' ', ' ', ' ', 4, 5, 6]
```

---

The *old-school*, for-loop way:

```
lst=["1,2,3", " , , ", "4,5,6"]

res = []
for item in lst:
  if item[0].isdigit():
    res.extend(map(int, item.split(',')))
  else:
    res.extend(item.split(','))
print(res)  # [1, 2, 3, ' ', ' ', ' ', 4, 5, 6]
```

I would go with the second one for its clarity. One can immediately tell what it does upon looking at it. That being said, and you having edited your requirements, the first one does not look so convoluted after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace(",", "").strip()` in the if condition to check if it is a valid element. And you can also use `list.extend` to create your output.

**Ex:**

```
lst=["1,2,3"," , , ","4,5,6"]

res = []
for i in lst:
    if i.replace(",", "").strip():
        res.extend(map(int, i.split(",")))
    else:
        res.extend([""]*(i.count(",")+1))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, '', '', '', 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=["1,2,3"," , , ","4,5,6"]
list2=[]

for c in lst:
    i=c.split(',')
    if c[0].isdigit():  
        list2.extend(map(int,i))
    else:
        list2.extend(i)

print(list2)
```

This will give the output in the way you wanted.you can try it and see the result